# Is it possible to bind a function which returns an observable to an @Input?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I an angular 7 application which contains many different types of certifications and applications for those certifications.  In the process of creating a new application I must load data from the data server depending on the type of certification and application being instantiated.  Because of the asynchronous nature of rxjs Observables  returned from the services I'm trying to pass everything as an Observable from one component to another.

Based on what I've read and other questions I've seen answered here I have the following code in the template on the component I'm attempting to instantiate:

**new-bcaba.component.html - Template**

```
  <div class="open-card-BG" *ngIf="CurrentPage == 1">
    <instructions [InstCertType]="ParentCertType$ | async" [InstAppType]="ParentAppType$ | async"></instructions>
  </div>
```

**new-bcaba.component.ts - Typscript**

```
export class NewBcabaComponent extends ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

  //public ParentCertType$: Observable<CertType>;
  //public ParentAppType$: Observable<AppType>;

  public constructor(NewInject: Injector) { 
    super(NewInject, '2', '1', 11);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    //this.ParentCertType$ = this.ShowCertType();
    //this.ParentAppType$ = this.ShowAppType();
  }

  private ShowCertType() : Observable<CertType> {
    console.log("... ShowCertType called ... ");
    return this.BaseCertType$;
  }

  private ShowAppType() : Observable<AppType> {
    console.log("... ShowAppType called ... ");
    return this.BaseAppType$;
  }

  // Accessors
  public get ParentCertType$() : Observable<CertType> {
    return this.ShowCertType();
  }

  public get ParentAppType$() : Observable<AppType> {
    return this.ShowAppType();
  }
```

I've tried using the accessors and setting member variables directly but both ways result in the same kind of error.

```
... ShowCertType called ...                           new-bcaba.component.ts:27 
... GetCertType in Certification Component called ... certification.component.ts:49
... FindCertType in Model-tools.service called ...                  model-tools.service.ts:53
... GetCertTypes in Model-tools.service called ...                  model-tools.service.ts:48

ERROR TypeError: fn is not a function                  NewBcabaComponent.html:3
    at pipe.js:18
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at piped (pipe.js:18)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.pipe (Observable.js:91)
    at ModelToolsService.push../src/app/_services/model-tools.service.ts.ModelToolsService.FindCertType (model-tools.service.ts:55)
    at NewBcabaComponent.push../src/app/certification/certification.component.ts.CertificationComponent.GetCertType (certification.component.ts:50)
    at NewBcabaComponent.get [as BaseCertType$] (certification.component.ts:54)
    at NewBcabaComponent.push../src/app/certification/application/new-bcaba/new-bcaba.component.ts.NewBcabaComponent.ShowCertType (new-bcaba.component.ts:28)
    at NewBcabaComponent.get [as ParentCertType$] (new-bcaba.component.ts:37)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NewBcabaComponent.html:3)
```

Based on the console.log messages the problem seems to be with how I'm binding the Observable to the template but it looks correct based on what I've read.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why you are not trying to use service for data share between components? If you dont know how can you do it, I can write such a code as an answer

Comment: I started out trying that but could not get it to work for component creation.  The problem is the asynchronous nature of the data coming back from the database server.  I can work with it with subscriptions once the component is created but when I need the data to instantiate the nested component it becomes problematic.  I'm passing observables hoping that the component would be created and initialized when the data becomes available.  There are 10-15 components nested per application and multiple service calls are needed to build one application.

Comment: Check your imports for rxjs operators and make sure your not importing from the internal packages. The error appears to be in the ModelToolsService and might be unrelated to the component itself or the template.

Comment: @cgTag I was importing the operators from rxjs/operators.  I found a way to stop the error but I don't understand why it works.  I've actually created a separate question to see if anyone can explain it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116454/should-the-rxjs-6-filter-operator-work-on-the-return-from-a-map-operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's possible.

I create a simple code to show how easy you van do that:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-service-x3qwbh?file=app/child/child-complonent/child-complonent.component.html

If you would like to correct your code, I guess you should change your template as below:

```
<div class="open-card-BG" *ngIf="CurrentPage == 1">
   <instructions [InstCertType]=ParentCertType$ 
  [InstAppType]=ParentAppType$></instructions>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for one part of the problem, as it turns out the issue was three different things all unrelated.  This fixed the title problem so I marked it as answered so thank you.  I was thinking I needed to stream in the observable as if I was displaying it in order to pass it on as an argument.  I see now what I'm actually doing is just passing the reference to be handled later.