# Should the Rxjs 6 filter operator work on the return from a map operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I had the following function:

***Original Function***

```
public FindCertType(CertTypeID: string) : Observable<ICertType> {
    console.log("... FindCertType in Model-tools.service called ...");
    return this.GetCertTypes()
      .pipe(
        map((CertTypeMap: IResponseObject<ICertType>) => {
          return CertTypeMap.Array
        }),
        filter((CertType: ICertType ) => CertType.Id === CertTypeID)[0]
      )
  }
```

This code resulted in the following error:

***Console Error***

```
... ShowCertType called ...                           new-bcaba.component.ts:27 
... GetCertType in Certification Component called ... certification.component.ts:49
... FindCertType in Model-tools.service called ...                  model-tools.service.ts:53
... GetCertTypes in Model-tools.service called ...                  model-tools.service.ts:48

ERROR TypeError: fn is not a function                  NewBcabaComponent.html:3
    at pipe.js:18
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at piped (pipe.js:18)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.pipe (Observable.js:91)
    at ModelToolsService.push../src/app/_services/model-tools.service.ts.ModelToolsService.FindCertType (model-tools.service.ts:55)
    at NewBcabaComponent.push../src/app/certification/certification.component.ts.CertificationComponent.GetCertType (certification.component.ts:50)
    at NewBcabaComponent.get [as BaseCertType$] (certification.component.ts:54)
    at NewBcabaComponent.push../src/app/certification/application/new-bcaba/new-bcaba.component.ts.NewBcabaComponent.ShowCertType (new-bcaba.component.ts:28)
    at NewBcabaComponent.get [as ParentCertType$] (new-bcaba.component.ts:37)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NewBcabaComponent.html:3)
```

When I modified the function to put the filter inline with the map the error went away and it started working as I expected.

***Modified Function***

```
public FindCertType(CertTypeID: string) : Observable<ICertType> {
    console.log("... FindCertType in Model-tools.service called ...");
    return this.GetCertTypes()
      .pipe(
        map((CertTypeMap: IResponseObject<ICertType>) => {
          return CertTypeMap.Array.filter(CertType => CertType.Id === CertTypeID)[0];
        })
      )
  }
```

While my problem was solved with the modification I don't understand why this works but the first version doesn't.  I was importing the "filter" and "map" operators from 'rxjs/operators' for the original code and as I understand the operators inside pipe should work on the returning observable from the previous operator so filter should work on the return of map.  Can anyone explain why that doesn't work?

Comment: Array.filter() is not the same thing as the RxJS filter operator. One transforms an array into another array by applying a predicate to every element of the array, the other accepts or rejects events emitted by an observable.

Comment: @JBNizet - according to the Rxjs documentation "Filter items emitted by the source Observable by only emitting those that satisfy a specified predicate." In my first example as I understand it map is returning an observable of an array so wouldn't the filter be checking each element of the array inside the returned observable as items individually or does it see the array as one item?

Comment: No. the filter operator is called for every item emitted by the observable. In this case, each emitted item is an array. The the filter operator receives an array as argument, and must decide if this array should be emitted or excluded. If you want to emit a different, filtered array, then you need to transform each emitted array, using the map() operator.

Comment: @JBNizet - I see, so that is why the second example works because I'm filtering the map's array and returning a single element.  Is it possible to modify the observable to emit the the elements of the array one at a time?

Comment: Yes. Using the mergeMap() operator for example.